# mod_rewrite and URL conflict

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a site to get info about other websites.
What I want to do is this:

> **myurl.com/site/example.com** -> original URL is
>   **myurl.com/work.php?query=example.com**.

And that, I know how to do.

But the problem is when I put, instead of *example.com*, also **http://** or **https://** before the "clean" URL, the Server understand another thing:

> **Not Found** The requested URL /site/http://www.example.com was not found on this server.

My .htaccess file now is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^q/([^/]*)$ /?id=$1 [L]
```

What may I do to get this works properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern: `([^/]*)` is matching anything that **isn't a `/`**. So if you add a "http://" or "https://" in front of "example.com", well, it's got `/` in it, two of them, so your pattern will refuse to match it. You could try to create an optional match for the http part:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^q/(?:https?://|)([^/]*)$ /?id=$1 [L]
```

or change the `([^/]*)` pattern to also match `/`'s:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^q/(.*)$ /?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I solved using

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^q\/([a-zA-Z0-9/_.]+)$ /?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^q\/http:\/([a-zA-Z0-9/_.]+)$ /?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^q\/https:\/([a-zA-Z0-9/_.]+)$ /?id=$1 [L]
`


But your solution is more clean. Thank you!